# Negative to chassis or separate wire?

Tags: resistance, automotive, efficiency, conductors

In automotive applications typically battery negative is connected to the chassis, right. This makes the chassis be at the same potential as battery negative, but when completing a circuit, ultimately the charge needs to return back to the battery. Bearing in mind that the chassis is made out of steel and the return path could be well within 4-5m range, does this increase the overall resistance of the circuit?

I'm assuming carmakers don't care about this since they have "unlimited" power, but in my case I'm running a 1kW electric motor (40+V) off of a (rather small 500Wh) battery, so would it make sense to run an additional copper trace to my motor negative instead of using the chassis?

Comment: You should measure if it makes more sense to use the chassis as return path for current or a separate copper wire. One thing I also might ask is why do you delinerately want to use the chassis as return path and cause potential differences to your chassis?

Comment: Although steel (generally) has a higher resistivity than copper, there is a lot more steel in a car chassis than there typically is copper in a wire. I would hazard to guess that the overall resistance of the chassis is typically less than the overall resistance of most copper wires in an auto, except perhaps to the very large wires connecting directly to the battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bearing in mind that the chassis is made out of steel and the return path could be well within 4-5m range, does this increase the overall resistance of the circuit?

Yes. That's why for any electronics, you don't use the chassis as path but just lie an extra conductor (what's expensive about that is pulling the cable; the extra conductor core is relatively cheap, *especially* if that means you reduce possible sources of error and hence make your build more reliable).

> I'm assuming carmakers don't care about this since they have "unlimited" power,

that'd be news to me,

> but in my case I'm running a 1kW electric motor (40+V) off of a (rather small 500Wh) battery, so would it make sense to run an additional copper trace to my motor negative instead of using the chassis?

yes, ground shift due to resistive losses is a thing and problematic. A 1kW electric motor implies 1000/40 A = 25 A, that's not that little.

Problem to consider (if a bit out of scope here): Where do you get those 40V in an automotive application? Are you doing a DC/DC conversion from 12 or 24 V? In that case, having isolated output might have severe safety advantages, as you'd isolate what happens on the higher-voltage bus from the rest of the car. If so, can you maybe safely go even higher? At 220V, 1kW becomes very manageable with cheap cabling.

Comment: Its a fully DIY build - I have a 36V (~42V) battery. I was considering 48V or 60V but the problem were the prices at the time, I got my motor for around $50 - higher voltage ones were 2x or more expensive. Additionally if I run AC I'd need an inverter and that would be adding to the cost which I'm trying to keep down to minimum.

Comment: yeah, then go for a return cable